# Store and reuse tsfresh feature engineering performed

Tags: python, time-series, tsfresh

I am currently using the `tsfresh` package for a project (predictive maintenance).
It is working really well and now I want to implement it live.

However, the issue is that I don't know how to **store the feature engineering that has been applied to my original dataset in order to do the same feature engineering to the data that I am streaming (receiving live)**.

Do you have any idea if there is a parameter or a function that allows to store the feature engineering performed by `tsfresh`?
(I am using the `extract_relevant_features` function).

Comment: Your answer has some formatting problems. Tips for the future: use `\`` brackets for paths and code fragments; to start from a new line (while editing the post, I spotted you had wanted to perform that) use *double space* at the end of the line.

Comment: Don't use salutations: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 0):

After searching through various post it turns out that the answer is that you can save your parameter into a dictionnary (see [here](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/text/feature_extraction_settings.html#a-handy-trick-do-i-really-have-to-create-the-dictionary-by-hand)).
This dictionnary can be can later be called with the function **extract_features** to extract only those parameters.